# Reproducing John Snow's application of Voronoi

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I am designing a practical for food&health students who have never worked in GIS.

I wanted to have them make a modern version of John Snow's second [cholera outbreak map](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(00)02442-9/fulltext) using today's tools. I have most of the [data](https://blog.rtwilson.com/john-snows-cholera-data-in-more-formats/). What I am missing is the areas closest to each pump in walking distance.
The concept is similar to Voronoi/Thiessen. However, the math is different, since it cannot rely on Euclidean distance.

Ideally, I want the students to be able to compute it themselves, the result being either polygons or lines. Alternatively, I can compute it myself and supply them with the dataset.

Is there an easy way to compute those areas closest to each pump on foot in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: You're looking at a travel distance calculation. Can't pinpoint what exactly the tool is called in Arc.

Comment: I had this exact exercise but from an open source point of view (Qgis + Postgres) and we used pg_routing module from Postgres to compute distance

Comment: this tutotial maybe https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/route-tutorial.htm, but it's more of a workflow for spatial network analysis

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. The current (sketchy) workflow I have in mind is 1) generate a cost raster with streets pixels=1 and others=10, 2) calculate a cost accumulation raster from the various pumps, 3) apply a watershed delimitation to the raster of accumulated costs. But this is not something I can ask the students.

Comment: There is a guide here https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/map-a-historic-cholera-outbreak/

Comment: @Mapperz Thank you. But that's neither the right software nor the goal I am trying to achieve.